# Opengles image skewed while rotate texture on Z axis

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, game-engine

Hi I am developing an OpenGLES based android application, and I need rotate the texture on z-axis on real time. But the image skewed while I add a rotation to the model matrix.

The first image below is the original one, and the second one is the skewed image after rotation on z-axis.

[image]

[image]

Here are my shaders:

```
private final String mVertexShader = "" +
        "attribute vec4 position;\n" +
        "attribute vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
        "varying vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 modelMat;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 viewMat;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 projectionMat;\n" +
        "" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_Position = projectionMat * viewMat * modelMat*position ;\n" +
        "    textureCoordinateVarying = textureCoordinate;\n" +
        "}";
private final String mFragmentShader = "precision highp float;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D textureBackground;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D textureNumbers;" +
        "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinateVarying;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    vec4 background = texture2D(textureBackground, textureCoordinateVarying);" +
        "    vec4 foreground = texture2D(textureNumbers, textureCoordinateVarying);" +
        "    gl_FragColor = mix(background, foreground, 0.2);\n" +
        "}\n";
```

And with respect to projection, view and model matrix, here is their init function:

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM(model, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(rotation, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(view, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(projection, 0);

    Matrix.translateM(view, 0,0,0,-3.0f);
    Matrix.perspectiveM(projection,0,45,(float)mBackground.getHeight()/(float)mBackground.getWidth(), 0.1f, 100f);
```

And in onDraw function, I will update the value of the model matrix;

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //some function

    //update model matrix, and rotation is just a 4*4 identity matrix, and the degree is the z-axis rotation degree.
    Matrix.setRotateM(rotation, 0, degree, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(model, 0, rotation, 0, model, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(rotation,0);

    //draw my texture
}
```

I am pretty desperate now, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to kill this question on my own, actually I just made a stupid mistake, the ratio of projection matrix should be the width of surface view divided by the height of the same surface view, which should not be the ratio of your texture image width/height.